# sscanf won't capture second string match

Tags: c, string, parsing, scanf

I was coding a little thing in C, and ran on a problem:

I'm trying to parse a file, which contains lines formatted as such:

```
name: description text: 42
name 2: description text2: 75
```

So as i read each lines, i feed them to a scanf like so:

```
uint8_t buffer [512]={0};
uint8_t name[32]={0};
uint8_t desc[32]={0};
uint8_t chances;
```

[ ... ]

```
scanres = sscanf( buffer, "%31[0-9a-zA-Z ]:%31[0-9a-zA-Z ]:%d", name, desc, &num );
```

But even if scanres is "3" (correct behaviour); "desc" still prints as "" (empty string)

Can someone help me with this? What am i doing wrong?

[EDIT] 
Here is the code in situation:

```
  #define TINY_STRING_SIZE 32
// [...]
  FILE *conffp;
  uint8_t i=0;
  uint8_t scanres = 0;

  uint8_t buffer [512]={0};
  uint8_t name[TINY_STRING_SIZE]={0};
  uint8_t desc[TINY_STRING_SIZE]={0};
  uint8_t chances;

  if ((conffp = fopen(filename,"r+")) == NULL)
  {
     exit(0);
  }

  while ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, conffp ) != NULL ) {
    printf("[>] %s", buffer);
    scanres = sscanf( buffer, "%31[0-9a-zA-Z ]:%31[0-9a-zA-Z ]:%d", name, desc, &chances );
    if ( scanres == 3 ) {
      printf("[+] id:%d desc:%s\tname:\"%s\"\tchances:%d)\n", i, desc, name, chances);
      //looter_grab(looter, i, desc, name, chances);
      i++;
    }
    else
    {
      printf("ERR: scanf got: %d \n",scanres);
    }
  }
  fclose (conffp);
```

thanks, Larzuk

Comment: I edited my example. My file actually contains colon, not comma. Thank's for pointing out.
I take note for the size. thanks.

Comment: I Just tried, same problem. I updated the post with the code in situation.

Comment: Yes. TINY_STRING_SIZE is defined as 32

Comment: Wow, thanks. I was tinkering about that for so long! But, i don't get it, i red the sscanf function, but nothing could gave me a hint about that. What's going on?

Comment: Oh ok, nice catch. Thank you!

Comment: "What am i doing wrong?" IMO, the real wrong here is not using a good compiler with all its warnings enabled.  Such a compilation will readily point to the significant problem identified by [@xing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504953/sscanf-wont-capture-second-string-match#comment93880783_53504953).